# What is the c++ equivalent of Java's split()?

Tags: c++, parsing

I'm trying to read data values from a text file and store them in a data structure. I could achieve something like this fairly simply in Java but I am unsure how to best approach the problem.

A line of data is `x, y, sigma` like `1.1 1.2 1.3`. I know how to get the entire line into a string in c++, using `getline(myFile, string)` but I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or if it is, where to go from there. Is it possible to split the line then parse the split strings as `double` values?

My data structure looks like this:

```
struct datapoint {
   double x;
   double y;
   double sigma;
   double weight;
   double xSquared;
   double xy;
};
```

My questions are these:

Is there a way to parse numbers into structures, where each line of the `.txt` file is a `struct` in an array of `datapoint`?

If there is no direct method, are there equivalents in c++ of Java's `split()` and `Double.parseDouble(string)` methods?

Thanks.

Comment: I guess you want something like this? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: Sean, C++ iostream is intelligent. You basically do: `cin >> mydata.x >> cin mydata.y ...` etc. It will understand that it has to convert to the proper type and it understands the formats pretty well.

Comment: Incidentally, you wouldn’t use `split` for this in Java, you’d use a tokeniser such as `Scanner` which has a pretty direct equivalent in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just reading them in with

```
std::cin >> x >> y >> sigma >> weight >> xSquared >> xy;
```

might be the easiest solution for your problem...

However, if you really need to do the splitting, have a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/faq/sequences/strings/split/

Comment: Sorry, that is my question being unclear, each line of the text file goes into one data structure. Then each struct is part of a `datapoint dataArray[n]`

Comment: You just loop if you have more datapoint values to be filled.

Comment: Yes, you can do in a loop: std::cin >> dataArray[i].x >> dataArray[i].y >> dataArray[i].sigma >> dataArray[i].weight >> dataArray[i].xSquared >> dataArray[i].xy;

Comment: Precisely as Jan suggests. +1

Comment: The data is already in a text file and there are ~1000 lines, unless I'm missing something, your suggestion is keyboard input?

Comment: @Sean No, the suggestion works with arbitrary streams, no matter where they come from. File, standard input …

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm not great at c++ so I'm not sure how I would implement this. Could an example be given?

Comment: @Sean Jan’s example already shows that, it can be used *directly* for file streams. Just exchange `std::cin` for your file stream instance.